# MySQL COUNT IF with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to solve this LeetCode problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/get-highest-answer-rate-question/):

[image]

I have generated the `survey_log` locally:

```
mysql> select * from survey_log;
+------+--------+-------------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| uid  | action | question_id | answer_id | q_num | timestamp |
+------+--------+-------------+-----------+-------+-----------+
|    5 | show   |         285 |      NULL |     1 |       123 |
|    5 | answer |         285 |    124124 |     1 |       124 |
|    5 | show   |         369 |      NULL |     2 |       125 |
|    5 | skip   |         369 |      NULL |     2 |       126 |
+------+--------+-------------+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

I'd like to use this auxiliary table:

```
mysql> select question_id, if(action='show', 1, 0) as is_show, if(action='answer', 1, 0) as is_answer from survey_log;
+-------------+---------+-----------+
| question_id | is_show | is_answer |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
|         285 |       1 |         0 |
|         285 |       0 |         1 |
|         369 |       1 |         0 |
|         369 |       0 |         0 |
+-------------+---------+-----------+
```

Next, what I'd like to do is get the sum of the `is_show` and `is_answer` columns for each `question_id`. I thought that this would work:

```
mysql> select question_id, count(if(action = 'show', 1, 0)) as show_count, count(if(action = 'answer', 1, 0)) as answer_count from survey_log group by question_id;
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| question_id | show_count | answer_count |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
|         285 |          2 |            2 |
|         369 |          2 |            2 |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
```

However, this doesn't give me the expected output

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| question_id | show_count | answer_count |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
|         285 |          1 |            1 |
|         369 |          1 |            0 |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
```

What is wrong with the last query? I've looked at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html but can't quite seem to apply it to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) simply counts non-null values. so both `0` and `1` will get counted. What you need to do is [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) them:

```
select question_id, 
       sum(if(action = 'show', 1, 0)) as show_count,
       sum(if(action = 'answer', 1, 0)) as answer_count
from survey_log
group by question_id;
```

Note that since MySQL treats booleans as 0 (false) or 1 (true) in a numeric context, you can remove the `if` part of the query:

```
select question_id, 
       sum(action = 'show') as show_count,
       sum(action = 'answer') as answer_count
from survey_log
group by question_id;
```